# Live KML Feeds - From the Ground Up, How Would You Build It and Why?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, kml, google-earth

I found the "Live KML from PostGIS to Google Earth" post very informative but a bit daunting for someone new to the open source world of products like PostGIS and GeoServer.

If I am building the product from scratch, is the PostgreSQL / PostGIS - GeoServer combination the accepted best path to take?

What are some alternatives or strengths / weaknesses?

Comment: You should describe what you're trying to accomplish, there's usually more than one way to skin a cat

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Vadim. I developed a very basic system of taking raw data and preparing it for an Access database that could be used in ArcGIS to export the product as a KML. I would like to take that idea and limit the manual labor to the updating of a database, and have that database provide a live kml feed or at least a live update.